# How to scroll TListview inside THorzScrollBox?

Tags: c++builder, tlistview, tscrollbox

I am trying to put TListView inside THorzScrollBox (In c++ builder fmx project).
The issue is when i do this i loos the ability to scroll down on TListView.
Is there any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It was some wierd bug with the builder anchor property. Using align instead worked.